# Upgrade GEOS version on shiny apps.io

Tags: r, shinyapps

It seems that the current version of GEOS available on shinyapps.io is not at the right level.
This is the error message I am getting when trying to deploy my app:

> ** package ‘lwgeom’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
>   ** using staged installation configure: CC: gcc configure: CXX: g++ -std=gnu++11 configure: pkg-config proj exists, will use it configure: PROJ: 4.9.2 checking for pj_init_plus in -lproj... yes
>   checking PROJ:
>   epsg found and readable... yes configure: POSTGIS_PROJ_VERSION: 49
>   checking for geos-config... /usr/bin/geos-config checking geos-config
>   usability... yes configure: GEOS: 3.5.1 checking GEOS version >=
>   3.6.0... no
>   configure: error: upgrade GEOS to 3.6.0 or later
>   ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘lwgeom’
>
> removing ‘/opt/R/4.0.0/lib/R/library/lwgeom’

Is there anything I could do to by-pass this problem waiting for an update on the shiny apps side?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62165453/shiny-deployment-error-upgrade-geos-to-3-6-0-or-later-while-installing-package/62165986